# Redirecting to other Wix site

Tags: velo

I want to make a bilingual site but i don't want to do it the "normal" Wix way with buttons because i want to have a drop down menu so I have created 2 sites( one will be on the domain and the other one on a sub domain) and added 2 language images on the sites that I want to link. And this is where i have ran into a problem.

I don't know hot to link from one site to another. Does anyone know the answer to this?

I have tried this but I can't find how to [link](https://www.wix.com/support/html5/article/adding-and-linking-a-text-button) to other site.

Comment: when i go link on the pictures and want to choose to what i can link I cant choose pages from the other site

Comment: this sounds more like a question for WiX support -- stackoverflow is a programming forum, not WiX tech support.

Answer (score 0):

it ca be done with code but there is no need. when you click on link "page" means pages on this site. just pick 'web address' see this [link menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9BGa.png). if for some reason you have to it with code you can use wixLocation.to see [here](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-location/to)